# Best way to predict as trajectory path point

Tags: java, geolocation, linear-regression, prediction

I am recording a movement of a vehicle every 3 minute interval.So at every 3 minute I will know the location update of the vehicle.From this data I would like to predict the next point at each point.For example
the last five location updates are like something below:

```
    latitude,longitude,timestamp
    1.527219139 103.7791514,2017-08-21 00:03:00
    1.528935142 103.7805676,2017-08-21 00:06:00
    1.530651144 103.7812113,2017-08-21 00:09:00
    1.531895244 103.7819838,2017-08-21 00:12:00
    1.533353844 103.7832713,2017-08-21 00:15:00
```

With thid data I would like to predict the next point where it is heading towards.Is it good to use a linear regression or an extrapolation.Or are there any other methodologies to calculate the predicted latitude and longitude.Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the Earth is flat (seriously -- the math will just be unspeakable otherwise).

You need to decide how many data points you want to analyze to make the prediction. If you just take the last two data points then the problem is relatively simple (on a flat Earth). You've traveled for what appears to be three minutes (12:00 to 15:00), and your increase in latitude is 1.533353844 - 1.531895244, whilst your increase in longitude is 103.7832713 - 03.7819838. From those figures you can estimate the change in latitude per minute, and the change in longitude per minute. You can add those per-minute changes to the most recent latitude and longitude figures to estimate where you will be one minute from the last reading. And so on.

Linear regression will only be any use to you if you assume that you are traveling along something that approximates to a straight line. Using regression would enable you to "average out" errors in the recorded positions, but would not give you a better prediction unless your motion really was in a straight line.

You can use multiple data points in your prediction. For example, you can use the last three data points and fit the values to some sort of cubic polynomial. You can then use the parameters of the polynomial function to estimate the next data point.

Using more that three data points is really only practicable if you know something about the underlying movement that is being recorded (e.g., that it is a straight line, or curve of some particular shape).

Comment: So can I use ARIMA model in this case?

Comment: Maybe, but I don't think this is the kind of data that ARIMA is really meant for. Have you tried this question on a math forum? To be honest, I think this really goes beyond a software development question.